# Access to image in resources, external reference

Tags: c#, image, uri

I'm trying to get an Uri in my program for an image in .resx file in another project, referenced in my program project.

So, my program project named Program, and the library Libary, I can access to this image from Program with : Library.Properties.Images.icon_image (return bitmap)

My Program code like this :

```
Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("???")).Stream;
```

What can I put at place of "???" to get it from my Uri ?

Comment: I removed the tag from your title.